# Cassandra opens too many files - possible file descriptor leak

Tags: linux, cassandra, centos, file-descriptor

I'm very new to Cassandra, and I want to test it on a single node, and as soon as I build it on a CentOS server it opens hundreds of thousand files. When I run `lsof | grep java | wc -l` I get more than 140000, and if I start a client connection and run queries the number of descriptors goes up and up and up to nearly a million at which point the server stops. I have tried scrubbing the SSTables using `nodetool` and `sstablescrub`, I have tried deleting the data from `/var/lib/cassandra/data/` but I still get more than 50000 file descriptors open as soon as I build the Cassandra node. I have noticed in the `lsof` result that I have only one process ID (PID), but I have hundreds of process group IDs (PGID). Is that expected? Is it related to the number of nodes? The file descriptors for each process group are identical. Here is a small sample of how data seems duplicated:

```
java      20595 20654      root  198u  a_inode                0,9           0       6999 [eventpoll]
java      20595 20654      root  199u  a_inode                0,9           0       6999 [eventfd]
...
java      20595 20655      root  198u  a_inode                0,9           0       6999 [eventpoll]
java      20595 20655      root  199u  a_inode                0,9           0       6999 [eventfd]
...
java      20595 20656      root  198u  a_inode                0,9           0       6999 [eventpoll]
java      20595 20656      root  199u  a_inode                0,9           0       6999 [eventfd]
.... and so on.
```

There also other file descriptors like:

```
java      20595 20655      root  mem       REG              253,1       32296  201350741 /usr/lib64/libffi.so.6.0.1
```

Which show up that many times as well.

Is the installation corrupt or is Cassandra misconfigured?

I have read the documentation from DataStax here: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/troubleshooting/trblshootTooManyFiles_r.html,

And I have read almost all similar questions as it seems that it is a fairly common problem, but I don't think the exact same question has been raised anywhere.

Comment: I have something simular. lsof gives me over 4 Millions rows. I checked greping one particular file and got 250.. so about 250 different groups (or threads?) using the same file. But that still means around 16.000 unique opened files. I have big problems with "too many open files".. and Im using datetieredcompactionstrategy.

Comment: I think that the installation I made was corrupt because I made a new installation on a server split to three virtual servers so that I can have three nodes, and it worked fine. Try to make a clean install, and ideally - try to have more than one node. Cassandra just isn't made for a single node, I guess.

Comment: I have the same issue and I need to run my tests on a single server installation. I checked my installation, followed the documentation on datastax and I am still seeing the same issue. When I run lsof | grep java | wc -l I get more than 4740000. How do I get Cassandra to work?